# How did Harry Mudd transport Lorca off of the Discovery bridge?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In *Star Trek: Discovery, "Magic to Make the Sanest Man Go Mad,* Harry Mudd came to the bridge and used a peculiar hand motion to beam Captain Lorca off the bridge. He didn't even use a voice command.

[image]

A moment later, he was seen materializing in front of the viewing window, and he was kicking because he couldn't breathe.

How was this accomplished?

Comment: Are you asking why it's possible to transport someone into empty space, or why Mudd was able to make the transporters do this?

Comment: Presumably Mudd's ship had transporters as well as *Discovery*.  Transporters Mudd controlled...

Comment: I edited to clarify. I meant that he used some hand motion that Saru recognized, and Captain Lorca was beamed off the ship instantly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the point Mudd made it to the bridge, he had full control over the critical computer systems aboard *Discovery*, and being the drama queen he was and already planning to kill Lorca, could have easily programmed the computer to recognize that hand signal as an order to beam Lorca off the bow.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure the bridge is on top of the ship. If he'd beamed him off the bow, he'd be hundreds of yards from the ship, not just outside the viewscreen window

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that?